# WSO2 Getting POST PUT DELETE REST parameters

Tags: rest, parameters, wso2, wso2-esb

Is there a way to get the parameters set in a post-delete-put REST request? in a proxy or programmatically developing a mediator (i mean  in the MessageContext object passed to the mediate method)?

I know that parameters are appended to the url in a GET request e they appear by

```
 getProperty("REST_URL_POSTFIX");
```

What about the other CRUD commands?

Answer (score 0):

To get programatically, you can retrive those details from Axis2 messagecontext.

```java
HttpServletRequest obj = (HttpServletRequest)
        msgContext.getProperty("transport.http.servletRequest");
System.out.println("Method :" + obj.getMethod());
```

Here is a detail [post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/08/extracting-http-level-information-in.html)

Comment: You should access Axis2Messagecontext.. Get axis messagecontext from SynapseMessagecontext. http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/06/retrieving-axis2messagecontext-from.html

Comment: i did exatcly that. This is the code: 

org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MsgContext;
  axis2MsgContext = ((Axis2MessageContext) synapseMsgContext).getAxis2MessageContext();
  

   HttpServletRequest obj = (HttpServletRequest)axis2MsgContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST);

obj is null

Comment: I checked all the properties' map inside the axis2MsgContext ... i got 32 properties but there is no trace of "transport.http.servletRequest" property... i found HTTP_METHOD, RequestResponseTransportProtocol and many others... but net the servletRequest. do i miss anything? maype in the synapse proxy service?

Comment: what about this post? it seems to be similar tom my case: http://wso2.com/forum/thread/10508